# Cypress: while running cypress ,automatically redirecting to login page

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

while I am running the cypress code, it is automatically redirecting to home page, and filling on login part, How to stop this?

```
it('SubInterfaces',function(){
    
    cy.url().should('include','/spoke/create')

    cy.get('input').eq(15).type('cypress')
    cy.get('input').eq(16).type('34.43.45.56')
    cy.get('input').eq(17).type('22')
    cy.get('input').eq(18).type('345')
```

})

[image: redirecting]

Answer (score 2):

try using `cy.visit('/desired-URL');` at the start of your function.

Comment: this option already tired, but no changes, still redirecting to new url

Comment: And you are sure that cypress is redirecting you?

Comment: Could you add your code to the question?

Comment: check, this way I am doing

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: In the beginning, you are on the correct page and you get the 15th input field and type cypress in it. After that, you get redirected?

Comment: I highly doubt that cypress is redirecting you. Maybe you have something else like a submission button or something else that is redirecting you.